# GCE LetsEncrypt Error - Cannot locate wrapped file

Tags: google-compute-engine, bitnami, ghost-blog, ghost, lets-encrypt

I am running into an issue with executing 'letsencrypt-auto' on the GCE Bitnami Ghost image.
The issue can be reproduced using the base installer below:
https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/ghost

Here is the command I use, and it's output:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/archive/master.zip
sudo unzip master.zip
cd letsencrypt
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo ./letsencrypt-auto --debug
```

..install dependencies...

```
**Reading package lists... Done **
Reading package lists... Done
**Building dependency tree **
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version.
dialog is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
augeas-lenses is already the newest version.
libaugeas0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Checking for new version...
Creating virtual environment...
Cannot locate wrapped file
```

Dependencies were all installed without issue. I have tried from both the 'home' directory and the root of the drive.

I have also tried:

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d {domain}
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -w /home/bitnami/htdocs -d {domain}
```

Any ideas what could be causing the wrapped file issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks for the suggestions here:
https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt/issues/2554

The key with on Bitnami seems to be to run the command on the "bitnami console"
More info about this here: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/BitNami_console