# manage.py command in crontab not working

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, bitnami

I have created a executeable script .sh which contains code to run a django managemenet command.

cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. /path/to/env/activate
cd /path/to/project
/path/to/env/bin/python manage.py some_command
```

I can confirm this script and manage.py command is working by executing it directly on terminal

$ /path/to/cron.sh

When i do it same via crontab its not working as expected.

** What am i doing wrong ?? I can confirm there is nothing wrong with crontab, it executing the cron.sh file but **path/to/env/bin/python manage.py some_command** is not working as expected.

cron log also showing

```
CRON[14768]: (root) CMD /path/to/cron.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I am using bitnami django ami (ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS)

**Update**

After removing /dev/null i am getting this error now

```
"Cannot locate wrapped file"
```

Comment: Just letting you know - you can use the `/path/to/env/python` to run your programs in that virtual environment without having to activate it.

Comment: yeah i have tried that too

Comment: You might have to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable from within the cron script or pass the settings to the command via `--settings`.

Comment: Remove redirection to `/dev/null` to see the error that is outputted by the manage.py command.

Comment: Please note when i execute it directly from terminal like $ /path/to/cron.sh its working perfectly

Comment: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: None of the solution provided here works

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a PATH problem. I do not know if django uses specific paths that must be set but AFAIK the crontab PATH is really limited due to security reasons. Just to check if that is the problem you could do in a shell terminal the following:

`echo $PATH`

You will get a complete PATH for instance:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`

In your crontab, put it above your code:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`

Tell me if this works. If does, try to purge the provided PATH or even better provide absolute locations in your code.

I have to say that I don't know if you can perform a `cd` in the cron like this. I always used absolute paths or `cd /some/dir && /path/to/script args`.

P.S: I cannot make comments yet, for this reason I put it in an answer.

Comment: Here is what i have debugged so far

Comment: As crontab is tricky to debug when I face such kind of problems I first try to log into a file the execution by ```/path/to/cron.sh >> /tmp/log.out 2>&1```. If that does not reveal you some information, I sometimes make some log statements in the python code to log some data (you can do it simply by writting to a file or using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module). By that way you could try to figure out what is causing that unexpected way of working (or even knowing if it is being run in some way)

Comment: thanks for helping this is what i am getting Cannot locate wrapped file.

Comment: Hi again @RizwanMumtaz, I am not a Django guru, but it seems to be a stack environment issue. Checking this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641594/1086326) may be useful. More concretely [Cannot locate wrapped file issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2554).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your not using the script that Bitnami uses to load all the environment variables (/opt/bitnami/scritps/setenv.sh).

I would try using this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /opt/bitnami/scritps/setenv.sh
. /path/to/env/activate
cd /path/to/project
/path/to/env/bin/python manage.py some_command
```